# Java save text file

Tags: java

I have a JFileChooser that is set as a set Save Dialog and a jTextArea where I can write stuff, my problem is that when I save it, the text doesn't get saved. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
private void saveAsButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    SaveAs saveasbtn= new SaveAs();
    int retrival = saveOption.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
       {saveasbtn.saveAs(jTextArea2.getText(),saveOption);}
    }


 public void saveAs(String value,JFileChooser saveOption){

    try {
        FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter(saveOption.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
        fw.write(value);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SaveAs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the FileWriter in `saveAs` method. Use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so the writer is closed and output is written to file. Maybe contrary to its name, `FileWriter` is also buffered, though it has smaller buffer than `BufferedWriter`, so contents are not written to disk immediately. The code would go like:

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveOption.getSelectedFile()+".txt")) {
    fw.write(value);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SaveAs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a finally block after the catch and call `fw.close()` explicitly there (calling `fw.flush()` is redundant if closing the stream).

Answer (score 1):

You can force `FileWriter` to flush all written data to file immediately with `fw.flush()`.

Do not forget to `close` the file at the end.   After you do `fw.close()`, all data you've written will be automatically flushed to file and the file will be safely closed.

If you use try with resources, the file will be flushed and saved automatically.

```
 public void saveAs(String value,JFileChooser saveOption) {
    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveOption.getSelectedFile()+".txt")) {
        fw.write(value);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SaveAs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just calling `fw.close()` will suffice

Answer (score 1):

Use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to ensure your data is written out.

```
try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveOption.getSelectedFile()+".txt") {
    fw.write(value);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SaveAs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

You might also want to either let that `IOException` propagate from `saveAs()` (by adding `throws IOException` to the method signature) or do something else like return a `boolean` to indicate whether the write succeeded or not. Otherwise your program can't tell whether `saveAs()` actually worked or not.